# Mobile network turns on by itself after Android 4.0.3. update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync, mobile-network

I'm having HTC Sensation and I use wi-fi on a regular basis instead of mobile network (bad data plan). For the old Android version there was no problem, I just switched of background syncing and set option "Sync only via wi-fi".

After the update mobile network turns on automatically...

I couldn't find exact duplicate of "Sync only via wi-fi" in the update.

I went to Settings->Wireless&Network->Usage->Menu->Usage Settings -> "Restrict background data", but two problems still arise:

1. Can't get rid of Notification "Background data restricted"
2. Mobile network turns on automatically when decides to sync.

Any advises?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe turning Data Enabled to off (Mobile network settings on CM9) might help. In that way, it'll sync only when WiFi is available.

Comment: At Mobile network settings I have:

# Data roaming OFF
# Data roaming sound OFF
# Access Point Names
# Network Mode
# Network Operators
# Enable always-on mobile data OFF

CM9- what's that?

Comment: I think this might help. ICS introduced capping the Data Usage. There must be an option called as "Data Usage" which shows you a graph of your data usage. There's an option called as "Mobile Data". Switch that to off.

Might be wrong. I'm on CM9. Worth a try anyhow.

Comment: CM9 - CyanogenMod 9. It's a custom Android ROM.

Comment: Can anyone please tell, why has someone, DOWNed my answer? You could suggest an edit ya know.

Comment: I don't know If we are talking about same "Data Usage":
Settings->Wireless&Network->Usage->Mobile Network OFF
This was the first thing that I did, nevertheless, this morning woke up with no credit and half updated Facebook statuses.